# Kotlin wrap content issues while passing the value

Tags: android, android-layout

I created a badge as a textview and i'm passing my count to it. The issue that i've faced is the width - if i pass "512", visible will be only "51". I've tried changing it to "match-content" but it doesn't help.

activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tasks"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tasks_counter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/badge_top"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_tasks"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_task_inactive" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
                    style="@style/unselected_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_title_top"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/tasks" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

badge-circle.xml <- for badge background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#F45725" />
    <size android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" />
</shape>
```

activity.kt

```
    fun countTasks(tasks: String) {
        tasks_counter.text = tasks
    }
```

Looks like that: [image]

How can I make it auto resizable? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set `ll_tasks` linear layout width to `wrap_content` and `TextView` width to `wrap_content`.

You are restricting your textview size to `16dp`, where it's getting cut off.

Comment: Still the same result, I edited my post with currect code